# Graph API problems after AWS datacenter migration from Brazil to US/Oregon

Tags: facebook, amazon-web-services, facebook-graph-api

We started experiencing problems in the Facebook Graph API after migrating from the AWS Datacenter in Sao Paulo to the United States. We use docker to run a NodeJS API in both locations, in the brazilian replica all services work properly.

In the US datacenter, some users cannot see their Facebook pictures, or event perform a full authentication because a lot of required params such as birthday aren't there.

Already tried whitelisting the server's IP, could not found anything about it the the Facebook Developer's documentations and forums.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replying to myself, maybe this will help someone in the future.

The Facebook support opened a bug and then realized that our application was marked with alcohol content. In Brazil the min age to drink is 18 years old, in US is 21, so everyone between 18-20 was having issues with SDK permissions.

We unchecked the alcohol content in the Facebook App and it started working again.